# What is Amazon Route 53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I stumbled upon Amazon Route53. I wasnt sure what its purpose was.

I currently have a domain name registered. If I did use that service, would I point my domain to Route53, to redirect it to my server? If so, why not have my domain name point directly to my server? Maybe I am missing the point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon route 53 is nothing but DNS servers. Route 53 DNS have some additional features which facilitate integration with other EC2 services.

If you wish to use it, you define your domain to use Route 53 nameservers instead of registrar or some 3-rd party nameservers.

Comment: could you give an example? I am struggling to understand the difference between the DNS servers and domain providers such as godaddy.

Comment: so, say if I have www.somerandomdomain.com bought by godaddy. Would route 53 replace godaddy? or would I point my domain bought by godaddy to point to amazon route53, which I then point to my server?

Comment: GoDaddy is both - registrar and DNS provider. I.E. you do two things with it 1. Define which nameservers will be used by your domain (set by default to GoDaddy servers) 2. Define A, MX AAAA etc. records on those servers.

Comment: If you use route 53, or any other DNs service, like http://zoneedit.com, my https://www.net-me.net or any other, GoDaddy remains your _registrar_, but you define to use **not** goDaddy nameservers but some 3-rd party nameservers like ns1.zoneedit.com, ns1.net-me.net etc.

Comment: Normally you don't need Route 53, if your registrar gives you DNS servers (and usually it does) and you don't need any extra features not supported by your registrar.

Comment: @LucasTan I wouldn't say _needed_. route 53 have certain features and certain advantages and probably drawbacks. Use it if you wish, and don't use it if not.

Comment: @LucasTan For one example, you can use certain route53 feature to improve availability of your website, see http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/02/11/announcing-dns-failover-for-route-53/